# how to parse array of objects using json for iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I have a problem parsing the array of objects from the JSON result.

```
[
    {
        "first_name":"vijay",
        "last_name":"last",
        "creditCardNumber":"178978977779787979",
        "month":"02","year":"2012",
        "address":"Addres2"
    }

    { 
        "first_name":"vijay",
        "last_name":"last",
        "creditCardNumber":"178978977779787979",
        "month":"02","year":"2012",
        "address":"Addres2"
    }

    {
        "first_name":"vijay",
        "last_name":"last",
        "creditCardNumber":"178978977779787979",
        "month":"02","year":"2012",
        "address":"Addres2"
    }
]
```

I wish to extract `creditCardNumber` value from all objects in the array.

Comment: Your JSON data is **not valid**: values in an array must be separated by comma. As for parsing JSON, there are a few possible libraries: JSONKit, SBJSON, TouchJSON, yajl-objc.

Comment: be careful with those credit cards dawg...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Google "JSON Framework". Follow the (easy) instructions to install it.

Then go:

```
//let's say there's NSString *jsonString.

NSArray *userData = [jsonString JSONValue];

NSMutableArray *creditCards = [NSMutableArray array];
for (NSDictionary *user in userData) {
    [creditCards addObject:[user objectForKey:@"creditCardNumber"]];
}
```

You'll drop out the bottom of that with NSMutableArray *creditCards full of NSString objects containing the credit card numbers.

Comment: hi dude it exactly what i needed and u r really superb.thanku.could please explain about that.how that works.since www.json.org specified that [ means array { means object . i have little confusion please.....

Comment: Your JSON is an array of objects. So you mimic that in Obj-C. JSON Framework is going to parse jsonString and return whatever type of object the top level of the JSON is (in this case an array). So you catch it in an NSArray. Then each element of that NSArray is an NSDictionary, with a "creditCardNumber" field.

Answer (score 2):

@Dan Ray answer is correct, but if you want to avoid third-party librairies you can use `NSJSONSerialization`:

Assuming that `NSData *responseData` is containing your JSON.

```
NSArray *userData = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseData options:NSJSONReadingAllowFragments error:nil];

NSMutableArray *creditCards = [NSMutableArray array];
for (NSDictionary *user in userData) {
    [creditCards addObject:[user objectForKey:@"creditCardNumber"]];
}
```

Source: [NSJSONSerialization](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/foundation/reference/nsjsonserialization_class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSJSONSerialization).