# Recup specific ID from Json answer from api (objective-c)

Tags: objective-c, json, parsing

I have a specific username (`NSString *`) and I do a request to the api (via `sendSynchronousRequest`) to get all the users. The data collected have this pattern :

```
{"users":
    [{"id":3,"username":"Max","email":"max@xxx.com","rank":0,"level":0,"score":{},"first_name":null,"last_name":null,"date_birth":null},
    {"id":4,"username":"Guest","email":"ere@xxx.com","rank":0,"level":0,"score":{},"first_name":null,"last_name":null,"date_birth":null},
    {"id":5,"username":"Root","email":"localhost@local.com","rank":0,"level":0,"score":{},"first_name":null,"last_name":null,"date_birth":null},
    {"id":6,"username":"test_user","email":"test@test.fr","rank":0,"level":0,"score":{},"first_name":null,"last_name":null,"date_birth":null}
]}
```

and I'm interested in getting the id value for a specific username (like "4" for "Guest") to use it in other requests.

I tried to follow [how to parse array of objects using json for iphone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4972682/how-to-parse-array-of-objects-using-json-for-iphone) but got some problems due to the format {"xxx":[{...},{...},..]}

Any help will be appreciated. Thx for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First parse the JSON string and put it into NSDictionary and extract the NSArray of users then use NSPredicate to get the user you want

```
NSDictionary *usersDictionary = [jsonString JSONValue];
NSArray *users = [usersDictionary valueForKey:@"users"];
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"username = %@", userName];
NSDictionary *user = [[users filterUsingPredicate:predicate] firstObject];
NSNumber *userId = [user objectForKey:@"id"];
```

Comment: Thank you very much, it didn't work at first, I changed just a few things : 

    NSDictionary *usersDictionary = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:kNilOptions error:&error];
    NSArray *users = [usersDictionary valueForKey:@"users"];
    NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"username = %@", self.Username];
    NSDictionary *user = [[users filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate] firstObject];
    NSNumber *userId = [user objectForKey:@"id"];

And it works ! Thanks again for this ultra fast answer, it saves my day!